# How to know which code has been pushed last on Github

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed EGit on an eclipse IDE. I would perform the Git action commit, push,pull on EGit and then use Jenkins pipeline to be triggered based on commit on my Github repository. 
Is there a way i can check which code has the last commit on the repository, using Github API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `sh` `git` on the workspace to get these details by adding this step to your pipeline,

`sh "git log -1 --pretty="format:%h"`

this should be returning SHA of the latest commit.

if you want to know the file changes the made on the latest commit you could do

`git show -1 --pretty="" --name-only`

or

`git show --pretty="" --name-only <SHA>`

Comment: I want to know the name of the source code. Is there a way the i can do it using the SHA of the latest commit.

Comment: when you say name of the source code do you mean file names?

Comment: i have updated answer to extract file names alone from last commit